# Can I add onFocusChangeListener to sub item of ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, event-handling, onfocus

I want add focus change listener to sub item of my ListView, I have tried `listView.setOnFocusChangeListener()`, but this just listen to focus move away from listview or move in listview.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find wrong way.`setOnItemSelectedListener` is OK.